# screen logging not working over ssh terminal

Tags: linux, logging, debian, gnu-screen

I want to run "screen" on a debian linode server, starting up over a ssh terminal window.  I'd like a shell script to start and detach a screen, so that a process can continue when I log off. I'd also like the logging file screenlog.0 to be produced, so that there's a record if the process crashes.

But there's a problem in getting the log file to write.  Locally, on a mac terminal window,

```
% screen -dm -L sh -c 'echo hello'
```

works fine, "hello" gets written to screenlog.0.  But the same command issued in a ssh window to the server executes, but nothing gets written.
However, if in that window I go into screen,

```
% screen -L
```

and then do some stuff, the activity is written to screenlog.0 (on the server).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the screen() command can have problems.  The above command sends no output to screenlog.0 under 'Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)' , while 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS' writes the odd message, "error: could not start server! try running as root!", to screenlog.0, even when running as root. 'Linux Mint 18.1' and MacOSX run correctly.

I was advised to use the venerable unix command "nohup" to solve my problem of detaching a process and logging its output, even when you close the ssh connection.  Ordinarily, when you close a terminal window, the signal SIGHUP is sent to any processes that were started there.  But

% nohup myprog > logfile.txt &

works perfectly.  Old way, good way.